# How to redirect page on button click event

Tags: javascript

I am using a button on my form. How do I link to another web page/file when clicking on that link? Here is the code I tried, but does not work.

```
<button class="btn" data-bind="click: function() { document.location.href=$(this).attr('RiskAssessmentMain.aspx'); }">back</button>
```

Comment: You should really clean up the title of this question. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, otherwise I'd try to myself

Comment: oh sorry...forgot to set the title

Comment: No problem, just thought it wouldn't really be useful when looking at a list of questions or for searching purposes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<input type='button'value='back' class="btn" onclick="document.location.href='RiskAssessmentMain.aspx';"/>
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/wzy4B/

Comment: yup, wanted to do that but I had to wait like 60secs and went to have a victory dance first. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

set the url you want to go in `<form>` **action** attribute.
then use a `submit` instead of `button`.
Here is an example.:

```
 <form action="http://google.com">   
    <input type="submit" value="Google">
 </form>
```

Comment: I have to use a button unfortunately. Thanks for your answer anyways

Comment: The default behavior of a `<button>` is to submit a form, so it's the same thing as `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: OK I saw that thanks. I was wrong in my assumption. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You Can try this one

```
<script>
      function open_win() {
           window.open("http://www.google.com")
      }
</script>
```

Or you can also Do it like this

```
<script>
       function openWin() {
            myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
            myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
            myWindow.focus();
       }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

and this the css

```
nav
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:350px;
    left:600px;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #FFD700; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    color:black;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background:     #FFD700;
    color:white;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color:black;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: maroon; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    background:     #CFB53B;border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #996515;
}
```

Comment: While this might technically work (haven't actually tested all the CSS), I don't think it's really the right direction to go based on the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"><button type = 'submit' class = 'btn'>Let's Go Home</button></a>
```

We can also use a tag. we have to just remove text-decoration for the button look. something like this.