# Wordpress redirect within plugin files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, redirect

[image]

There is a button in **customer-car-list.php** that I have to click,then redirect to show the contents of  **customer-car-details.php** It's not a form, just a button.
I can get the click action using this code but redirecting have no idea after failing **wp_redirect()**

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_item']) && isset($_POST['car_id'])) {
  //yey! button clicked but how to redirect?
}
```

I have tried using **wp_redirect()** but could not solve it.
Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2):

in car list you might have list of all cars so for this you have list out heading and button to redirect. You fetch link using,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Using javascript you can redirect page,

[How to redirect page on button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766940/how-to-redirect-page-on-button-click-event)